# Flutter: How to change font of Appbar text?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's my current code of my main.dart. I tried putting 'theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Bebas Neue Regular')' under the title: Text('SMARTID'), as I want to change the Appbar text which is SMARTID, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: MyApp(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override 
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Smart ID',
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff05B068),
            title: Text('SMARTID'),
            theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Bebas Neue Regular'),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @RavinderKumar I'm quite new to StackOverFlow. I'm not sure why it unaccepted.

Comment: @RavinderKumar But your code worked, anyways I've accepted your answer again. Thanks by the way!

Comment: You are most welcome:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it like,

```
appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff05B068),
            title: Text('SMARTID',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'YOUR_FONT_FAMILY')),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
```

**EDIT:** Do not forget to create fonts folder like this image,

[image]

Then open your pubspec.yaml and declare fonts like this,
[image]

**DO not forget to get packages**

Comment: Is it necessary to put weight? What happens if you don't put weight?

Comment: It is not necessary at all. I just gave you a sample from my own code. For more, you can head over to [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts)

Answer (score 4):

In addition, you also can declare the textStyle directly in your ThemeData, if you want to apply iny our entire app. Like this:

```
final ThemeData themeData = ThemeData(
  ...
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
  ),
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

appBar doesn't have any theme property. So, you can add your fonts in your appbar by applying style to your title like,

```
appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff05B068),
        title: Text('SMARTID', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Tomorrow"),),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
```

You can download any fonts from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)

Place your custom fonts inside your **root project > fonts package**

Meanwhile, add font details in your pubspec.yaml file like,

```
fonts:
    - family: Tomorrow
      fonts:
```

## path to your different custom fonts with styles

```
        - asset: fonts/Tomorrow-Regular.ttf
          style: normal
        - asset: fonts/Tomorrow-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Tomorrow-Black.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Tomorrow-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
        - asset: fonts/Tomorrow-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: fonts/Tomorrow-Light.ttf
```

You're set.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text style of a Text by passing it a TextStyle, that you create with the font family, size, etc..

Something like this

> Text('SMARTID',style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'open_sans'))